# PHP not sending IP over

Tags: php

I've been trying to test if I could send my IP to my email.
It doesn't seem to work.

```html
<html lang="en-GB">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="description" content="My Personal Website">
<meta name="keywords" content="MSHLondon, Sabri, Meeran">
<meta name="author" content="Sabri Meeran">
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="mshLogo.ico"> 
<title>Test.</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$message = "IP Address: " . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . "\r\n";
mail('notmyrealemail123@gmail.com', 'DataRecieved', $message);
?>
<span>Just a test.</span>
</body>
</html>
```

[Changed email, but everything else is the same]

It doesn't seem to send, even in spam.

Comment: Do you have a mail server like Postfix running that would actually send that e-mail?

Comment: How are you running this script?

Answer (score 1):

The remote host will be blank - since you are running this from the command line.

That will be populated when a web request comes to the PHP application.

If you want the server IP, use `$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']`

**UPDATE**

```
$message = '<html lang="en-GB">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="description" content="My Personal Website">
<meta name="keywords" content="MSHLondon, Sabri, Meeran">
<meta name="author" content="Sabri Meeran">
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="mshLogo.ico"> 
<title>Test.</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>IP Address:'. $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . '</p>
<span>Just a test.</span>
</body>
</html>';

mail('notmyrealemail123@gmail.com', 'DataRecieved', $message);
```

Your code is not correct, try using that snippet instead.

Comment: Don't forget the HTML header.

Comment: So, what should the entire thing look like? Thanks, by the way ;P

Comment: Just put that code in a php file, then run it with php

Comment: Did you have any luck?